# Setup Alfresco to, upon upload, automatically set a custom content model and bring up aspect management

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, dashlet

So I'm working on a project with pretty specific client requirements. The want a document that, once uploaded, is automatically given a custom content model (which I've already made) and then, immediately after upload, allow the user to select aspects to add to it. If the user cancels out of the aspect selection, the document needs to be deleted.

We have a full Maven space setup for alfresco and share development and have our standard-document.xml in alfresco/src/main/resource/alfrescco/extension/model.

The question I have is, where in my share environment do I start working on this process? Would it be best to make a custom dashlet that deals with the upload process, or is there some class or function I can rewire within the Slingshot/Spring Application Context. I couldn't find any existing plugins or share amp files that I could use as a reference. Is there anything out there that currently has something similar to this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're using Alfresco's Share client, right?
you'll have to have to tweak Share's JavaScript components:

- add a custom flag to "metadataRefresh" event object that is fired in x-upload.js
- tweak handling of "metadataRefresh" event in documentlist.js to call the relevant action

it's gonna be a though JavaScript implementation task.